# How to serialize slice of ArrayCollection using JMS Serializer?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, jms-serializer

I want to serialize into JSON entity `Category` with collection of `Presentation` entities (see below) to use for REST API.

The endpoint will look something like this `/api/v1/categories/1`

When dataset is small and when `Category` only has only 5-10 related `Presentations` then the resulting response is not too large. However when `Category` starts to have let's say 100 or 200 related `Presentations` then obviously I do not want to return all of them, but would like to "paginate" the results, eg. when calling endpoint:

`/api/v1/categories/1?page=2`  - would return only "2nd page"

`/api/v1/categories/1/page=3`  - would return "3rd page"

or even it can be with `offset` and `limit`:

`/api/v1/categories/1?offset=20&limit=10`

but the problem is: **how to make JMS serializer serialize only a slice of the collection?**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @JMS\Expose()
     * @JMS\Groups({"get-category"})
     */
    private $title;


    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Presentation", mappedBy="categories", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @JMS\Groups({"get-category"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    private $presentations;


    // ...

}
```

ps. I know that for example if I want to get always **first** 5 elements of the collection, I can add created `@VirtualProperty` and slice the doctrine `ArrayCollection` as shown below. But the problem here is that I cannot pass the offset parameters to this method. As it would be called internally by JMSSerializer somewhere...

```
/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty()
 *
 */
public function getFirstFivePresentations(){
    return $this->presentations->slice(0,5);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to limit the collection results in your query, rather than always loading 100% of them and trying to slice them after the fact?

Comment: @JasonRoman your concern is correct in case association's fetching strategy is `LAZY` or `EAGER`. However in my case I have marked the association as `EXTRA_LAZY` http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html  `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Presentation", mappedBy="categories", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")` which means that collection wouldn't be loaded in full. And all SELECT queries are deferred till the moment I call `slice(0,5)` which results in `SELECT xxx FROM presentation OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5`.

Comment: Couldn't you just write a custom query though to retrieve what you need?

Comment: @JasonRoman I think I am starting to see your point... let me try..

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't simply rely on the associations here, especially for an API, and especially in a case where hydration might really slow down the retrieval anyway

Comment: @JasonRoman how would you suggest to build the query? I tried doctrine `Paginator` https://gist.github.com/dimkir/e79b2a878c8e0d6aec29 but it only limits the quantity of `Categories`, not quantity of `Category->Presentation` entities...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102504/discussion-between-dimitry-k-and-jason-roman).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement the incorrect approach in your REST API. Each entity must have it's own path.

The right way is to have two different endpoints:

`/api/v1/categories/1` -> Serialized category **with no presentations**

`/api/v1/categories/1/presentations` -> Serialized collection of presentaions

And here you should use pagination

`/api/v1/categories/1/presentations?offset=20&limit=10`

Comment: I agree with you that including `presentations` within the `categories` resource doesn't seem to be textbook solution. However from the application I use I have a view which shows /List of categories with few sample presentations/  and I do not want to make multiple API requests from the app to retrieve this data.  And I see more use cases for similar scenarios - most of the views of the app require a mix of data from different resources....

Comment: Create property `$presentationPreviews` in `Category` and don't map it with doctrine annotations, create setter for it. Exclude `$presentations` from being serialized. In controller, after categores were fetched, loop them and fetch their presentations using repository class (set criteria and limits you like). Set fetched collection of presentations using `$category->setPresentationPreviews($fetchedPresentations)`. Configure serialization to serialize `$presentationPreviews` property. And that's it!